# Getting a result that matches one column with another

Tags: mysql

Hi I'm using mysql to be able to match one column with another column in one table and it needs to give me the result.

I know that mysql has been depreciated, but the fiddle that I'm using doesn't have mysqli. So I'm using the mysql as a learning base at the moment.

Here is my statement

```
SELECT `overview` FROM products WHERE `overview`=`image`
```

Here is the fiddle: [fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2dbde)

What my table looks like

```
id | name      | image        | overview
91 | product 1 | product1.jpg | This is the overview of product 1
92 | product 2 | product2.jpg | This is the overview of product 2
```

What the result needs to be is if overview is in the same row as image then display the overview.
The expected output would be:

This is the overview of product 1

This is the overview of product 2

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: can give example output do u need??

Comment: MySQL has not been depreciated. Its value is, presumably, little changed from the day Oracle purchased it. PHP's mysql_ API has however been *deprecated*. This may or may not have had an impact on the value of that suite of functions.

Comment: Post expected output..As it is not clear what u wanna achieve..

Comment: I've updated the question to have what the expected output should be. I hope that it clearer now

Comment: No even now its not clear. You are comparing which column with what??

Comment: I'm comparing the image and overview columns

Comment: And then you want them in the result although they are different in your sample data and your desired result. But you actually want them when they are equal. It's also always a good idea to have rows in the sample data that should not be in the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to use a join between the table and itself:

```
SELECT p.overview
     FROM products p
         JOIN products p2 ON p.overview = p2.image
```

In this way you will see only the values of the 'overview' column that will match the values of the 'image' column